# obtaining mysql data without while loop to reduce speed?

Tags: php, mysql

If I only have one row that I'm getting through

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT id,user,comments FROM user WHERE id='15' AND user = '15'");
```

is there a way to just get the comments from that one row without going through a while loop :

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
$comments = $row['comments'];
}
```

Is there something similar besides using a while loop? If my data has thousands to millions of data, a while loop will take a long time? Is this a more logical way to locate a certain row and reduce its speed?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're only returning one row then only fetch once.

```
if ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  $comments = $row['comments'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = mysql_query("
SELECT id,user,comments 
FROM user 
WHERE id='15' 
AND user = '15' 
LIMIT 1");
```

The LIMIT 1 will stop the query after the first result

Comment: And what about fetching the results?

Comment: you can still use `while`, or `if` as Ignacio suggested, either will test for a result first. if you're not going to use an `} else {` condition (to handle what happens when no records are returned), you could just use `$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);` on it's own.

Comment: but the performance issue was handled via `LIMIT 1`, and it doesn't really matter how you access the data.

Answer (score 0):

when you have more than one rows in resultset, then and then only you need to do it in loop else to fetch single row you are not required to put result set in loop.

you can do it like this..

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 1){
   if($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
       $comments = $row['comments']; 
   }
}
```